# StreamWriter no escribe headers de las columnas de datatable en CSV

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Tengo este código, el cual me escribe los registros de un `datatable` en un archivo *CSV*; no me pinta las cabeceras de las columnas, solo los registros, ¿cómo puedo pintar los encabezados?. `t` es el nombre de mi `datatable`, que trae las filas de datos.

```
                StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(RUTAEXCEL);
                foreach (DataRow dr in t.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < t.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {

                        if (i + 1 == t.Columns.Count)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(dr[i].ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sw.Write(dr[i].ToString() + ",");
                        }
                    }
                }
                sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer un recorrido por las columnas antes de iniciar la escritura de las filas para *incluir* el título de cada columna como línea de encabezado en el archivo.

Por ejemplo:

```
StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(RUTAEXCEL);
try {
    //línea de cabecera
    for (int i = 0; i < t.Columns.Count; i++) {
        if (i + 1 == t.Columns.Count) {
            sw.WriteLine(t.Columns[i].Caption);
        } else {
            sw.Write(t.Columns[i].Caption + ",");
        }
    }
    //líneas de datos
    foreach (DataRow dr in t.Rows) {
        for (int i = 0; i < t.Columns.Count; i++) {
            if (i + 1 == t.Columns.Count) {
                sw.WriteLine(dr[i].ToString());
            } else {
                sw.Write(dr[i].ToString() + ",");
            }
        }
    }
} finally {
    sw.Close();
}
```